# What is wrong with a volatile type deduction in template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, g++, volatile, clang++

I have a template function:

```
template <typename T>
inline void Acquire_Store(volatile T* ptr, T value) {
  // ...
}
```

When I try to invoke it like this:

```
volatile Node* node;
Acquire_Store(&node, static_cast<Node*>(nullptr));
```

The both g++, clang++ compilers say something like this:

> deduced conflicting types for parameter 'T' ('volatile List::Node *'
>   vs. 'List::Node *')

What is a correct way to invoke this template function?

**Update.**

Now I'm not sure about `node`'s type - maybe, I should change it to `Node* volatile node;`?

I want the variable `node` to be volatile, but not the pointed object.

Comment: @abyss.7 doing `static_cast` you force compiler to think that `T` is a two different types at the same time :) -- it is probably will be possible on a quantum computers of the 2113 year, but not nowadays :)

Comment: @zaufi maybe `static_cast` is a wrong thing - but I don't know, how to make a proper call - that's what the question is about.

Comment: what exactly do you want? obviously you have to change either signature or a call site.

Comment: For example, I can make this: `volatile int a; Acquire_Store(&a, 0);` - without any problems. I want to make the same thing with `volatile Node* node;`.

Comment: that is only a coincidence :) because literal '0' has an `int` type in instantiation of `Acquire_Store`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substitution and deduction is not lexically like with a macro. `volatile T*` will not become `volatile Node**` but `volatile Node* volatile*`. The second volatile comes from the template. That makes T equal `volatile Node*` for the first parameter.

Try to free yourself from sticking the volatile always at the beginning, but put it qhere it belongs according to the actual type. A volatile pointer has the volatile after the star, not before it.

Answer (score 0):

compiler actually you told about your problem clearly enough: you can't have `T` be different types at the same time (of instantiation). that is because you cast the second parameter incorrectly.
for example you may "fix" it like this:

```
// kate: hl C++11;
#include <iostream>

struct Node {};

template <typename T>
inline void Acquire_Store(volatile T* ptr, T value)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    volatile Node* node;
    Acquire_Store(&node, static_cast<volatile Node*>(nullptr));
    return 0;
}
```

then output will be

```
void Acquire_Store(volatile T*, T) [with T = volatile Node*]
```

but I still don't understand what are you trying to achieve...

Comment: I've updated the question. Maybe, you will get a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem is that the `volatile` qualifier is binding to whatever type T is.

```
template <typename T>
inline void Acquire_Store(volatile T* ptr, T value)
```

So when `T = Node *` for the above, it is the *pointer to Node* that is volatile and ***not*** the Node itself. To make the pointed to object volatile qualified it has to be part of T. This presents a problem because your second parameter is non-volatile -- T cannot both be volatile and non-volatile at the same time.

What you can do is make `T = volatile Node *` and then remove that volatile qualifier from the second argument using type_traits:

```
template <typename T>
inline void Acquire_Store(T *ptr, typename std::remove_volatile<T>::type value);
```

Note all this applies to const qualifier as well. **[Ideone demos this for const qualifier](http://ideone.com/9JB7Uk)**.